# Dotnet Maui MenuFlyout , how to bind to Collection

Tags: maui

There is no ItemsSource property on the dotnet maui 7 ContextMenu MenuFlyout. How can we bind this to a collection. Surely they don't expect us to hardcode this? I'm trying to get a list of these within a MenuFlyoutSubItem

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/context-menu?view=net-maui-7.0

Thanks

Comment: why would `MenuFlyoutItem` have an `ItemsSource` property?  It is not a container

Comment: OK thanks but how to create a dynamic collection of MenuFlyoutItems

Comment: You could do it in the code behind, because `MenuBarItems` is a collection that implements `IList<MenuBarItem>`. That's also mentioned in the link you provided yourself.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Seems use binding cannot work. you could create a observablecollection of MenuFlyoutItems then add to the MenuBarItems.

Comment: Doesn't look as though this can be done for the ContextMenu items

Comment: As there is no itemsSource property, actually it seems like a hardcode .

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted.  Although "binding" might not be the right term in the strict sense, the point of the question is valuable in its own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway we found a workaround, as we needed a dynamically generated context menu, we now use a TapGestureRecogniser to handle a right click event and then in the code behind create the whole context menu itself each time and attach it to the view.

```
void ContextMenu_Selected(System.Object sender,Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TappedEventArgs e)
{
    HorizontalStackLayout hs = (HorizontalStackLayout)sender;
    MenuFlyout mf = new MenuFlyout();
    MenuFlyoutItem flyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
    flyoutItem.Text = "Menu text"
    mf.Add(flyoutItem);
    FlyoutBase.SetContextFlyout(hs, mf);
}
```

Comment: Although a very different scenario, this answer is also useful when a static context menu shows up on an element in an ItemTemplate/DataTemplate that is bound to a collection.  When defined in XAML there's currently no way to identify from which item in the collection the menu was displayed.  An amusingly similar set of words to describe something totally different, yet with a similar workaround.